# MonoTouch deploy to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have developed a number of apps using MonoTouch, and been using the emulator for the iPhone, now I need to deploy me application to my iPhone for further testing.

I have purchased the iPhone SDK from Apple, but I can't find how to deploy and activate the MonoTouch application to my iPhone.

Any pointers please?

Answer (score 16):

As has been already stated you obviously need the paid version of MonoTouch and the iPhone SDK. Once you have those sorted you need to create a developer certificate in the iPhone developer portal, download it to your dev machine and add it into your keychain.

Once you have done that you must create a provisioning profile for your physical device, which again you do through the developer portal. Once you have the provisioning profile, download that to your machine, and add it to the iPhone via the Organiser app in XCode.

Then fire up MonoDevelop, and if it's all gone to plan then you should have the option of deploying the build to your iPhone. You can check that MonoDevelop has correctly detected your certs by opening up the Project Options window and under the Build section and under iPhone Bundle Signing, you should see your developer cert and provisioning profile.

Full details of the steps required on the [Apple iPhone Dev Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the MonoTouch docs on building for distribution

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Building_for_Distribution

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes I have followed this and it is all set up correctly.

When I compile I get:

"No Valid iPhone code signing keys found in keychain."

Comment: Have you downloaded a certificate from the Apple developer portal and added it to your keychain?  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you have to have the Monotouch deployment license from Novell to deploy to a device.

Comment: Yes I have that too, as well as iPhone SDK

Comment: The $500+ one? Mono has a free version for simulator only use and then a paid version for limited deployment on device.

Comment: then it sounds like you havent created a cert, downloaded it to your machine and added it to your key chain

Answer (score 0):

According to your statement:

> When I compile I get: "No Valid iPhone code signing keys found in
>   keychain.

This is actually a Xcode question more then a Monotouch one;

The message indicates that your keychain does not provide the signing keys used to generate the certificates and provisioning profiles.

If you follow apple's steps on generating certificate(request), followed by profiles they will also state you might want to export your private key (p13 file) and keep it somewhere safe. 
If you move to another laptop for instance, you will need to import that key again to make the machine a valid one.

If something went wrong (ie: you accidentally removed your private key, ..) this message will be shown since there is no way for Xcode to verify that the profiles are being used on a valid machine.

Go to [this instruction page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action) (apple account credentials needed) to check if the steps have been followed and check in the Keychain access app on your mac if under My Certificates you see a developer certificate and - if you unfold it - you can see the private key as a child node.